# Issue vertical align on table/tabularx

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, booktabs

[image]

As you can see from the picture I'm having a few troubles centering some text inside specific cells (mostly `\multirow` cells). My intent is to have the highlighted texts both vertical and horizontal centered, like it's already happening in the first cell (i.e. the one with the `Attack vector` string). What am I missing in order to achieve that?

Here's the relative Latex code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

% Packages and some configs
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\GC}[1]{\cellcolor{Gray}} % Grey Cell

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % Vertical center alignment
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % Horizontal center alignment

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{
>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C % 0.4 of the overall width
>{\hsize=0.9\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C % 0.3 of the overall width
>{\hsize=0.9\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C} % 0.3 of the overall width
    \toprule
    \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Metric Value} & \textbf{Numerical Value} \\ \midrule

    \multirow{4}{*}{Attack Vector (AV)} & Network (N) & 0.85 \\
    & \GC{20} Adjacent (A) & \GC{20} 0.62 \\ 
    & Local (L) & 0.55 \\
    & \GC{20} Physical (P) & \GC{20} 0.2 \\
    
    \GC{20} & Low (L) & 0.77 \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\GC{20} Attack Complexity (AC)} & \GC{20} High (H) &  \GC{20} 0.44 \\

    \multirow{3}{*}{Privileges Required (PR)} & None (N) & 0.85 \\
    & \GC{20} Low (L) & \GC{20} 0.62 (or 0.68 if \textit{Scope} is \textit{Changed}) \\
    & High (H) & 0.27 (or 0.5 if \textit{Scope} is \textit{Changed}) \\

    \GC{20} & None (N) & 0.85 \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\GC{20} User Interaction (UI)} & \GC{20} Required (R) & \GC{20} 0.62 \\

    & None (N) & 0 \\
    & \GC{20} Low (L) & \GC{20} 0.22 \\
    \multirow{-2}{0.4\textwidth}{Confidentiality (C) Integrity (I) Availability (A)} & High (H) & 0.56 \\ 
    
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package

Comment: Try to specify a number of physical text lines for `\multirow`. In case of "Privileges Required (PR)", the number should be 5 not 3 and you should have the text centred. Also, this argument does not need to be an integer, 5.5 would also be allowed.

Comment: @Celdor amazing! And I guess the same goes for the last cell ("Confidentiality, ..."), with `\multirow{-3}`. I didn't though I needed to specify the actual physical number of lines, but just the row ones :/

Comment: @Fabio yes, it should be -3. If some some cells in your table had any extra vertical spacing, you would need to add a fraction to the number, that's why I mentioned 5.5 can also be used.

Answer (score 2):

The layout of your table is not exactly easy to follow. I would therefore like to suggest the following, rather different, layout; its main goals are simplicity and easy readability.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % for smash[b] macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % for 'threeparttable' env.
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\textit}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l S[table-format=1.2] @{}} 
\toprule
Metric & Metric Value & {Numerical Value} \\ 
\midrule
Attack Vector (AV)
       & Network (N)   & 0.85 \\
       & Adjacent (A)  & 0.62 \\ 
       & Local (L)     & 0.55 \\
       & Physical (P)  & 0.2  \\ 
\addlinespace
    
Attack Complexity (AC)
       & Low (L)       & 0.77 \\ 
       & High (H)      & 0.44 \\
\addlinespace

Privileges Required (PR)
       & None (N)      & 0.85 \\
       & Low (L)       & 0.62\tnote{a} \\
       & High (H)      & 0.27\tnote{b} \\
\addlinespace

User Interaction (UI)
       & None (N)      & 0.85 \\
       & Required (R)  & 0.62 \\
\addlinespace    
     
\mytab{Confidentiality (C), Integrity (I),\\ 
       \quad Availability (A)}
       & None (N)      & 0    \\ 
       & Low (L)       & 0.22 \\
       & High (H)      & 0.56 \\ 
    
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] or 0.68 if \textit{Scope} is \textit{Changed}
\item[b] or 0.5 if \textit{Scope} is \textit{Changed}
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `multirow` command has an option to adjust vertical alignment of the content of a cell -- See page 3 and 4 of its manual. Adding that vertical adjustment option to your MWE shifts the content of the two cells to the required position.
Mind you: in the adjusted code the two additions are done visually. There might be a way to do that exactly measuring the height of the multirow cell and halving that. But that is beyond my LaTeX knowledge ..

```
\documentclass{article}

% Packages and some configs
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}
\newcommand{\GC}[1]{\cellcolor{Gray}} % Grey Cell

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % Vertical center alignment
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % Horizontal center alignment

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{
            >{\hsize=1.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C % 0.4 of the overall width
            >{\hsize=0.9\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C % 0.3 of the overall width
            >{\hsize=0.9\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}C} % 0.3 of the overall width
        \toprule
        \textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Metric Value} & \textbf{Numerical Value} \\ \midrule
        
        \multirow{4}{*}{Attack Vector (AV)} & Network (N) & 0.85 \\
        & \GC{20} Adjacent (A) & \GC{20} 0.62 \\ 
        & Local (L) & 0.55 \\
        & \GC{20} Physical (P) & \GC{20} 0.2 \\
        
        \GC{20} & Low (L) & 0.77 \\
        \multirow{-2}{*}{\GC{20} Attack Complexity (AC)} & \GC{20} High (H) &  \GC{20} 0.44 \\
        
        \multirow[c]{3}{*}[-12pt]{Privileges Required (PR)} & None (N) & 0.85 \\ % [-12pt] added
        & \GC{20} Low (L) & \GC{20} 0.62 (or 0.68 if \textit{Scope} is \textit{Changed}) \\
        & High (H) & 0.27 (or 0.5 if \textit{Scope} is \textit{Changed}) \\
        
        \GC{20} & None (N) & 0.85 \\
        \multirow{-2}{*}{\GC{20} User Interaction (UI)} & \GC{20} Required (R) & \GC{20} 0.62 \\
        
        & None (N) & 0 \\
        & \GC{20} Low (L) & \GC{20} 0.22 \\
        \multirow{-2}{0.4\textwidth}[5pt]{Confidentiality (C) Integrity (I) Availability (A)} & High (H) & 0.56 \\ % [5pt] added
        
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    
\end{document}
```

Result (you may need to tinker the given values a bit more as the `Low` entry doesn't align nicely with the rest of the text):
[image]